# DispatchQueue.main.async logic repeated in the condition

Tags: swift

I have the following logic, and as you see main queue does exactly same things in if and else condition. I wonder how I can rewrite this logic in better shape or refactor.

```
if isPostItem {
 DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
  self.mainVM.postItems(id: itemId) { error in 
   DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
     inputBar.sendButton.stopAnimating()
   }
  }
 }
} else {
 DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
   self.mainVM.retrieveItems() { error in 
   DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
     inputBar.sendButton.stopAnimating()
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: What is `DispatchMainQueue`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just embed your

```
   DispatchMainQueue.main.async{ [weak self] in
     inputBar.sendButton.stopAnimating()
   }
```

in its own function and then call that new function from the two closures.

e.g.

```
func stopAnimatingAndOrDoOtherStuff() {
   DispatchMainQueue.main.async{ [weak self] in
     inputBar.sendButton.stopAnimating()
   }
}
```

and then:

```
 DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
  if isPostItem {
     self.mainVM.postItems(id: itemId) { error in 
     stopAnimatingAndOrDoOtherStuff()
     }
  } else {
   self.mainVM.retrieveItems() { error in 
     stopAnimatingAndOrDoOtherStuff()
   }
  }
 }
}
```

The new function makes it easy to add in any additional lines into the common closure.